# How to find period in time series – with fuzziness?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics

Given a set of timestamps, I want to find a periodic grid most of them fall into.

Example set that falls into a grid with a period of 30:

```
10, 40, 72, 99, 164, 172, 190
```

Three fuzziness parameters here:

1. small deviation (72->70, 164->160) is acceptable;
2. some amount of samples (172) fall out of the grid. Their acceptable percentage is also set by some parameter;
3. sample around 130 is skipped, but is also ok. Acceptable amount of "holes" can also be somehow set.

Looking at intervals between the samples, I can think of searching for the greatest common divisor (GCD), again, with some fuzziness.

Please advice an approach to this problem.

Comment: is the dependence always linear?

Comment: I thought of linear as the simplest one to start from. Further I'd like to detect more complex patterns in data too.

Comment: could you link the data? or at least some chunk of it

Comment: unfortunately, no real data is available atm. Just up to building the prototype that'll give the simplest feedback to users providing data.

Comment: I ask since the algorithm pretty much depends on the data. so you are looking for an idea only? nothing particular?

Comment: Yes - just the idea. My hope is that there's some method like linear regression that can be applied to the task. Varying the three fuzziness params I expect to find, or not to find periodic patterns in provided data.

Comment: Apply a Fourier transform and look for a frequency with a large amplitude.

Comment: @Prune how can I precisely set the three fuzziness parameters in Fourier transform?

Comment: You don't; FT will exhibit fuzziness as lesser amplitudes, some of them cancelling others at critical points.

Comment: @Prune [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/syk31fs9/) a FT of the sample data from the question I built – lost in interpreting the results.

Comment: I'm confused, myself.  Fourier frequency analysis doesn't *finish* with complex numbers.  That set needs integration to get the spectral analysis.  http://www.gaussianwaves.com/2013/05/a-tutorial-on-fourier-analysis-fourier-series/ gives a nice view.  Fourier did a lot of things; I'm suspect that I didn't give you a sufficiently accurate term the first time.
The Wikipedia page is also good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform